# Error when using collect_list in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have two versions of Spark code. The first uses structured streaming with a Kafka source:

```scala
dfStream.printSchema()
//root
//|-- dt: string (nullable = true)
//|-- ip: string (nullable = true)
//|-- device: string (nullable = true)

val dfWindowed = dfStream                                                
    .groupBy($"ip")
    .agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list($"device")).alias("devices"))
    .writeStream                                             
    .outputMode("complete")                                              
    .format("memory")                                                        
    .start()
```

The second reads from files. But the data is really the same as above:

```scala
logDF.printSchema() 
//root
//|-- dt: string (nullable = true)
//|-- ip: string (nullable = true)
//|-- device: string (nullable = true)

logDF.repartition(32)                                                                                                   
    .groupBy("ip")
    .agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list($"device")).alias("devices"))
```

The problem is, while the second works well, the first keeps giving me the following error:

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:177)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 9 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 9.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 28, c3-hadoop-prc-st3417.bj, executor 3): java.lang.RuntimeException: Collect cannot be used in partial aggregations.
```

A long sentence.. but the error seems to be the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Collect cannot be used in partial aggregations.
```

I found a couple of related SO questions, but no solutions worked so far. Any suggestions on the following are much appreciated:

1. the meaning of "partial aggregation" & the reason why no such problems with static (non-stream) dataset,
2. a workaround...

Comment: In short - complete mode with non-reducing function would require asymptotically unbounded memory (with each step you just add more data).  It's not going to fly. And the problem is just [a bit less bad](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) with batch processing, where amount of data is by definition bounded. Workaround? Honestly, just don't try to do anything like that. Append to persistent storage, use probabilistic data structure, or whatever fits your requirements (which are not clear here).

Comment: @user6910411: You are correct, 'complete' mode will eventually lead to oom in this case. But here I know the sink/mode is irrelevant (though distracting...), because 1) it didn't have the chance to output anything.. 2) I actually tried different output mode/sink, the error was the same.

Comment: Here is the what I meant to do: group the dataset by a column (say "IP"), concatenate other columns (user ID's, time, etc... appeared under each IP), then save each "IP, concat-ID-string, concat-Time-string, ..." record to database.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could consider workaround as `groupByKey -> reduceGroup` chain, for example:

```scala
case class Data(ip: Int, column1: String, column2: String)

import spark.implicits._

val path = "/tmp/spark-streaming/test-data"

  Seq(
    (1, "val1", "field1"),
    (1, "val2", "field2"),
    (1, "val3", "field3"),
    (1, "val4", "field4"),
    (2, "val1", "field1"),
    (3, "val1", "field1"),
    (4, "val1", "field1"),
    (4, "val2", "field2")
  ).toDF("ip", "column1", "column2").write.mode("overwrite").parquet(path)

  spark.read.parquet(path).printSchema()

  spark.read.parquet(path).show(false)

  spark.sql("SET spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference=true")

  val stream = spark.readStream.parquet(path).as[Data]

  val result =
    stream
      .groupByKey(_.ip)
      .reduceGroups { (l, r) =>
        l.copy(column1 = l.column1.concat(",").concat(r.column1), column2 = l.column2.concat(",").concat(r.column2))
      }
      .map(_._2)



   result.printSchema()

   result.writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/spark-streaming-checkpoint-test")
    .option("truncate", "false")
    .format("console")
    .outputMode("update")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination(300000)

Seq(
    (1, "val5", "field5"),
    (2, "val2", "field2"),
    (3, "val2", "field2"),
    (4, "val3", "field3")
  ).toDF("ip", "column1", "column2").write.mode("append").parquet(path)
```

This will result to something like following:

```
+---+-------------------+---------------------------+                           
|ip |column1            |column2                    |
+---+-------------------+---------------------------+
|1  |val1,val2,val3,val4|field1,field2,field3,field4|
|3  |val1               |field1                     |
|4  |val1,val2          |field1,field2              |
|2  |val1               |field1                     |
+---+-------------------+---------------------------+
```

NOTE: aggregation operations is not supported in Complete mode as of 2.3.1

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a UDAF, as suggested [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html).

```scala
class ConcatString extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
    // This is the input fields for your aggregate function.
    override def inputSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType =
        StructType(StructField("value", StringType) :: Nil)

    // This is the internal fields you keep for computing your aggregate.
    override def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(
        StructField("concated", StringType) :: Nil)

    // This is the output type of your aggregatation function.
    override def dataType: DataType = StringType

    override def deterministic: Boolean = true

    // This is the initial value for your buffer schema.
    override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
        buffer(0) = "-1" 
    }

    // This is how to update your buffer schema given an input.
    override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
         buffer(0) = (buffer.getAs[String](0) + ",,," + input.getAs[String](0))
                    .stripPrefix("-1,,,")
    }

    // This is how to merge two objects with the bufferSchema type.
    override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
        buffer1(0) = (buffer1.getAs[String](0) + ",,," + buffer2.getAs[String](0))
                    .stripPrefix("-1,,,")
                    .stripSuffix(",,,-1")
    }

    // This is where you output the final value, given the final value of your bufferSchema.
    override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
        buffer.getString(0)
    }
}
```

Note: Separator is ',,,'. The seemingly weird "-1" initialization and subsequent stripPre/Subfix()'s are my poor solution to inadvertently concatenating initial values of *buffer*.

Usage is as following:

```scala
val udafConcatCol = new ConcatString
val dfWindowed = dfStream                                                
     .groupBy($"ip")
     .agg(udafConcatCol(col("device")).as("devices")
     ....
```